# C# Specflow: How to call a method having dynamic tables as an argument in another folder's class

Tags: c#, cucumber, bdd, specflow

I have two folders Folder A and Folder B containing different classes and methods.

Folder A

> Class A
> -> Method1 (Which uses data from the table mentioned in its feature file)

Folder B

> Class B
> -> Method 2

Problem: I want to call Method1 in Method2. I have imported the necessary class and other data but still, it is not working.

Method 1:  public void WhenAdminFillsAllTheDetails(Table table) // this contains long list of data such as name, phone, city, date of birth etc.

Method 2: This method is calling Method1 as shown below:
CNES_Steps.WhenAdminFillsAllTheDetails(table) // I created an instance of Table -> table

Comment: Define "Folder" in your context? When classes are compiled, it doesn't not care about folders. Do you mean namespaces?

Comment: is method 1 public, how is it's class initialized in method 2's class.  Also what do you mean it's not working? is there a compile error or run time error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to call the Method1 (**Which uses data from the table mentioned in its feature file**) in another method. I was facing this issue due to the argument of the Table instance. As the method was of particular feature file, the other method which didn't have same feature file could not call the method. Here, I was not getting any error but the browser used to shut down instantly the moment it opened while running the tests.

Later I found that this is actually not possible as Table has some limitations.

If I want to share data among multiple bindings then I have to use the Context Injection method. I did the same. I created a new separate POCO class just for sharing data and then I am using the same class in 2 different bindings.

Hope this explanation helps others too who are facing the same problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and I can't comment either. But if method 1 is not static, you can't call it from another class without creating an instance of such a class.

Solution 1: Make method 1 static

```
public static void Method1 ()
```

Solution 2: Make an instance of the class that contains method 1

```
classFromOtherNameSpace obj = new classFromOtherNameSpace ();
obj.Method1();
```